# start app Timeout-PCF DEV

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

```
Hi Anyone,
```

I was trying to push my application into PCF DEV installed in my Laptop
it was throwing Error "start app Timeout"
PFB complete trace logs it says" Crashed" while copying into container failed.

```
  2016-09-25T02:05:31.32+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Downloaded app package (414.2M)
    2016-09-25T02:05:31.33+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Staging...
    2016-09-25T02:05:47.56+0530 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Java Buildpack Version: v3.6
     (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#5194155
    2016-09-25T02:05:47.84+0530 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8
    .0_71 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_7
    1.tar.gz (found in cache)
    2016-09-25T02:05:51.47+0530 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .j
    ava-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (3.6s)
    2016-09-25T02:05:51.53+0530 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Me
    mory Calculator 2.0.1_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calcul
    ator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.1_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
    2016-09-25T02:05:51.79+0530 [STG/0]      OUT        Memory Settings: -Xms160M -X
    X:MetaspaceSize=64M -Xss853K -Xmx160M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64M
    2016-09-25T02:05:51.79+0530 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Spring Boot CLI
    1.3.2_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/spring-boot-cli/spring-boot-c
    li-1.3.2_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
    2016-09-25T02:05:52.67+0530 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Spring Boot CLI to
     .java-buildpack/spring_boot_cli (0.8s)
    2016-09-25T02:09:31.57+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Exit status 0
    2016-09-25T02:09:31.57+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Staging complete
    2016-09-25T02:09:31.57+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading droplet, build artifacts
    cache...
    2016-09-25T02:09:31.57+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading build artifacts cache...
    2016-09-25T02:09:31.57+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading droplet...
    2016-09-25T02:09:32.24+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Uploaded build artifacts cache (108
    B)
    2016-09-25T02:10:51.16+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Uploaded droplet (464.1M)
    2016-09-25T02:10:51.34+0530 [STG/0]      OUT Uploading complete
    2016-09-25T02:10:56.21+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Creating container
    2016-09-25T02:10:57.78+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully created container
    2016-09-25T02:13:24.09+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 9006d
    0e4-3a3e-4ea3-8a9a-400ee980851c payload: {"instance"=>"81cb959d-9a2f-40c5-774e-8
    74d95fb9a6e", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"Copying into
     the container failed", "crash_count"=>1, "crash_timestamp"=>1474749803843656553
    , "version"=>"a1b05faa-ae62-4f1e-a633-caa78a281cc8"}
    2016-09-25T02:13:24.16+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Creating container
    2016-09-25T02:13:26.69+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully created container
    2016-09-25T02:16:13.30+0530 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 9006d
    0e4-3a3e-4ea3-8a9a-400ee980851c payload: {"instance"=>"cde8bf35-f8bb-4c66-55e2-b
    e2e1855b0ce", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"Copying into
     the container failed", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1474749973094952167
    , "version"=>"a1b05faa-ae62-4f1e-a633-caa78a281cc8"}
    2016-09-25T02:16:13.44+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Creating container
    2016-09-25T02:16:16.21+0530 [CELL/0]     OUT Successfully created container
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an engineer on PCF Dev. You're more than likely running out of disk space on your app push. PCF Dev ships with limitations on the container disk space by default to accommodate laptop environments. It looks like you have a rather large application. Try pushing it with the Cloud Foundry `-k flag` to specify container disk space.

```
Ex: cf push <app-name> -k 1G
```

More information can be found here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#disk-quota

Comment: Would you know how to specify the download and installation location when running 'cf dev start' for the first time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620032/change-pcf-dev-installation-location