# Change PCF Dev installation location

Tags: windows, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I'm trying to setup Pvotal Cloud Foundry DEV on my machine, but my main hard drive does not have enough room and our System Administrators frown on us installing applications onto the C drive. I have an additional D: drive with plenty of space on it, and I would like to get PCF DEV to download and/or install all files there.

How do I specify the download and installation location when running 'cf dev start' for the first time on a windows machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PCFDEV_HOME` environment variable to specify the path where the ova and vm files will reside.

Comment: Thanks for you help on this. I got it up and running, but now I want to access it from other machines on the network. Is that something you could help me with? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639600/access-pcf-dev-from-external-machine-on-same-network-as-host

Comment: I've downloaded in one machine and copied the .cfdev to another machine. In the new machine, after set PCFDEV_HOME=E:\VM\.cfdev\state, where the VM is located, when I run "cf dev start", it still start to download. Can you help?

Comment: When I start "cf dev start", I see files in .cfdev folder is deleted and it's restart the download again. How can I make it use the existing file w/o download again? I can't let it download because I am using the phone line, don't have 20G data.

Comment: @user1288329 It should not be downloading again. Files may be getting deleted and created again, but downloads are not happening again. If you're using the latest version, the downloaded files all go into `.cfdev\cache`