# Access PCF DEV from external machine on same network as host

Tags: windows, networking, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

My intention is to use PCF DEV as an integration test environment for our CI server, as well as a place to demo proof-of-concept projects.
I have Pivotal Cloud Foundry DEV setup on a private network in a windows environment.
I'm able to access everything fine from the host box, but I and others on my team need to be able to access it from other machines on the network using the cf cli as well as just accessing deployed services.
I'm not savvy in the ways of DNS proxy, so I'm not sure whether using Acrylic is the right move here or not, since the host machine will have internet access even though other's accessing it will not.

How do I access PCF Dev from other machines on the same network as the host machine?

Comment: did you managed at leaset to login to the app-manager (https://uaa.local.pcfdev.io/login) remotely?

Comment: @yuvalsimhon I have not been able to the app manager remotely. I can only access it from my local machine that is hosting the PCF DEV virtual machine.

Comment: @yuvalsimhon Since it is a closed network, and PCF DEV shares the host computers IP, I was thinking I should be able to setup our networks dns to forward *.local.pcfdev.io to the host machine, but I don't know anything about whether that needs to be set to a certain port or not (I'm a networking newb).

Comment: @yuvalsimhon See the accepted answer and my comment on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use netsh portproxy functionality and add a redirect from local network IP address to pcfdev host only IP address 192.168.11.1

more on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Specifically I had to map "127.0.0.1:80" to "192.168.11.11:80" and "127.0.0.1:443" to "192.168.11.11:443". Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I also had to allow inbound traffic on those localhost ports so the windows firewall would not block requests.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with detail comments and making the the life of others easier!

Comment: Hi @Pytry I tried the same steps as mentioned by you but getting Error performing request: Get https://127.0.0.1/v2/info: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: What address then will be for this remote access? Like locally it's http://<appname>.local.pcfdev.io, what will be the url from outside?

Comment: you have to use hosts file or add a zone (local.pcfdev.io) on your dns server for proper name resolution during remote access. e.g. add the entry (assuming it is routable/accessible locally) to the hosts file on remote machine:
192.168.11.11 appname.local.pcfdev.io

Comment: Updated answer located @ https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cfdev/issues/67#issuecomment-450693175 for latest version of cfdev as of 2019-01-03